# Finding the critical point and local extreme value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I find the critical point of the following function.

$f(x)=x^{2/3}+2x^{-1/3}$

This is what I did.

$\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{2}{3}x{^\frac{-4}{3}}$

$\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$

but how do I simplify it and get the critical point.

Comment: i will see what i can do

Comment: (Thanks @julien.) You might want to try doing a small amount of work to get $f'(x) = \frac{2(x-1)}{3 \sqrt[3]{x^4}}$.

Comment: Hmm what work did you do to get the (2x-1) I mean it is a common denominator so you multiply by 3 cube root(x^3)?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[3]{x^4} = (\sqrt[3]{x})^4$. (I am assuming that $x>0$.) This leaves you with $\frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{ \sqrt[3]{x}}- \frac{1}{ (\sqrt[3]{x})^4} )$. Now how do you get a common denominator?

Comment: would it be multiplying (1)/cube root(x) times (cube root(x^3) so that it become cube root(x^4)

Comment: I understand how you took the 2/3 part out but I do not get the common denominator part...

Comment: First do $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad-bc}{bd}$. Then simplify.

Comment: I see I did  that part and got (cube root(x^4)-cube root(x))/((cube root(x^5)) then I got (2/3) (x^(1)/cube root(x^5)

Comment: I already told you to write $\sqrt[3]{x^4} = (\sqrt[3]{x})^4$. To make life easier, let $y = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and write the equations in terms of $y$. When you simplify, then expand $y$ to get the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align} 
f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{2}{3}x^{-4/3} 
& = \frac 23\left(x^{-1/3} - x^{-4/3}\right) \\ \\
& = \frac 23\left(x^{3/3}x^{-4/3} - x^{-4/3}\right) \\ \\
& = \frac 23 x^{-4/3}\left(x^{3/3} - 1\right) \\ \\
& = \frac 23 x^{-4/3}(x - 1) \\ \\
& = \frac{2(x-1)}{3x^{4/3}} \\ \\ 
& = \frac{2(x-1)}{3\sqrt[\large 3]{x^4}} \\ 
\end{align}
$$

Now, we have critical points where

- $f'(x)$ is undefined: at $x = 0$, as is $f(x)$
- $f'(x) = 0:$ This will occur if and only when the numerator is zero. In this case, $f'(x) = 0$ when $(x - 1) = 0 \implies x = 1$.

---

Let's look at the Wolgram Alpha graph below (the blue curve): We see that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. That is, there exists a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$. We also see that at $x = 1$ we have a local minimum. You can use the derivative to tell you when $f(x)$ is increasing ($f'(x) > 0), when decreasing ($f'(x) \lt 0$), and you already know where it is neither increasing nor decreasing, given the points we've found.

[image]

Comment: What did you use to plot? +

Comment: Hi! Is it good morning for you? I simply used Wolfram Alpha!

Comment: Yes it is rainy now. It is full of Oxygen. Nice to see you again. :-)

Comment: Nice to see you, too!  I didn't sleep at all last night! I just kept working, answering questions... (I did actually nap for two hours at 7:00 a.m., but maybe that's why I'm not doing so well tonight :-/  I should plan to get to bed before I feel too wound up to sleep! ;-) But feel wide awake!

Comment: I had too. No! please don't think such that, however, the OP's have right to agree or reject. You are doing so good. If you have done slow, so what can I say about myself? Freeze! :)

Comment: Take a complete rest. Your brain needs it. Have a nice sleep.

Comment: You put a smile on my face! You are doing so well yourself. You are a true gem on this site, as you are always so welcoming of askers and so kind to other users. Sincerely, you are a breath of fresh air on this site!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$
\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{x^{-\frac{4}{3}}}=x^{\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}}=x\quad\forall x\neq 0.
$$

Comment: How would I use this knowledge in my problem? I dont get it

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Set your differential equal to $0$, and do a little algebra. This will surely come up.